# Defining RecyclerView in a fragment (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

This is not an error in my code, I am new to android studio and just have a question about RecyclerViews.
When using the basic activity template, I have a perfectly working RecyclerView when I have defined it inside of the content_main.xml (Activity) 
Like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when I move the RecyclerView from the content_main **Activity** to the fragment_first **Fragment**, the code reads the RecyclerView as **null**
Like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**My question is, why does this happen?** Is it because RecyclerView must be defined in an Activity, or do I have to follow a different set of steps to make it work in a fragment?

For Reference, Here is my RecyclerView definition:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) mWordList.add("word"+i); //content that goes in recycler view

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview); //reference to recycler view
        mAdapter = new WordListAdapter(this, mWordList); //create and supply adapter
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); //connect adapter with the recycler view
    }
```

**Error message after moving to first_fragment.xml:**

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: I don't get your code exactly, but if you try to find the id of the recyclerview you need to find it inside the view where it is. You are setting a contentview for your activity but your recyclerview is inside the view of a fragment. You need to find the view when you inflate the view of the fragment.

Comment: ok that makes a lot of sense thanks